# Installing VirtualBox gives "dpkg : error processing package"

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, dpkg

`dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-4.3`is displayed on the terminal while installing VirtualBox.

*What can I to do install it properly?*
I tried downloading different versions of VirtualBox, but no use. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The message you have only tells us that there was an error but not what the cause was. Is there anything further up the line that tells you what went wrong?

Answer (score 6):

To install virtualbox, download the .deb file from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Select the architecture that best fits your machine. Once downloaded, open up terminal and and cd to the directory where you downloaded the file. Then, type

`sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-*`

and press ENTER. Let it run through the process. Once it's finished, pass or fail, type the following into terminal:

`sudo apt-get install -f`

This will install all of the dependencies of the .deb file that dpkg doesn't do. Any time you install a .deb file, always use

`sudo dpkg -i *file_name*`

What this does is it adds the program to the apt archives, and lists it as a failed install. It shows that it has unmet dependencies, and to install the dependencies and finish installing the program, you need to run

`sudo apt-get install -f`

Boom, you have what ever .deb file you downloaded successfully :)

Comment: this answer should be accepted. thank you it worked for me. upvoted :)